# apache kafka producer NetworkClient broker server disconnected

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I m newbie on the apache kafka and I have problem about the connection to apache kafka.When I run configuration with java based apache kafka producer its working but when I added packaged jar file and run on  apache metron kafka broker,error occure as seen below

```
2017-03-17 07:32:32 WARN  NetworkClient:568 - Bootstrap broker node1:6667 disconnected
```

configuration

```
bootstrap.servers=node1:6667
acks=all
retries=0
batch.size=16384
linger.ms=1
buffer.memory=33554432
key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Code :

```
sender.send(new ProducerRecord<S, String>(getSenderTopic(), (S) getSenderKey(),
          data), new Callback() {
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
              if (e != null) {
                LOGGER.error("exception ", e);
                sender.close();
              }
            }
          });
```

Apache kafka broker run on the apache metron and configuration host is setted node1:6667

I think its network side problem but what is your suggesition on it?.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after research , I have solve the problem , problem on the kafka versions  apache metron use 10.0.1 and we use 10.1.0 , changed on the pom xml problem solved.